# include all js files under a folder in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, tags

Can we include all js files in one folder in jsp page.
For example i had a folder name with ABC and js files under it is a.js, b.js and c.js.Instead of including js files individually in jsp page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ABC/a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ABC/b.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ABC/c.js"></script>
```

can we do like below format ???

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ABC/*.js"></script>
```

I mean i need to include all 3 js files in jsp page. can anyone help?

Comment: You can't do it like that, but you could do a loop to read the filesystem and get the list of all the js files and output the html to include them. But that would be a big waste of resources and slow your site down. Better to just type them all out.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<%
for(File f : new File(request.getContextPath() + "js").listFiles()){
  if(f.getName().endsWith(".js")){
     out.println("<script src='js/" + f.getName() + "' type='text/javascript'></script>");
  }
}
%>
```